# Ad popups showing on personal website deployed on VPS

Tags: web-application, malware, web-browser, server, apache

I have a Spring-MVC webapp deployed on a Hostinger VPS server (OS: Ubuntu 18.04, Apache2 + Tomcat servers). For some reason, every now and then, clicking on random regions within the web pages of my webapp causes malicious advert pages to open. The whole code for the webapp was written by myself and I have avoided using any malicious components. The VPS server itself was a clean install so I don't think that could be the source of these ads. I have tried this from multiple devices with the same result.

One thing I should point out is that the website is not running using HTTPS as I am yet to purchase an SSL certificate.

Is there a way to figure out why these ads keep showing up? What could possibly be the reason for these ad popups and what could I do to prevent this?

Comment: Your stream is getting hijacked. It's not the server, but the connection.

Comment: Are you aware of Let's Encrypt and their free TLS certs?

Comment: @schroeder Could you point me towards some resource that has more info on this kind of hijack? If the connection is being hijacked, is it reasonable to assume that any confidential data sent over prior requests would have be intercepted?

Comment: @schroeder I wasn't aware of the free Let's Encrypt SSL certs. Thanks for sharing the resource!

Comment: Because you have not encrypted the stream, anything you send or receive on that stream is open to the world. You should not be sending confidential data over unencrypted lines.

Comment: Stack Exchange uses Let's Encrypt for their certs. Take a look at the cert info in your browser! There is little reason not to have TLS on all sites.

Comment: OP, see https://superuser.com/questions/902635/isp-is-inserting-ads-into-web-pages

Comment: Is there a database component to this website? If so, it may be possible to inject scripts into content that display ads (and other mischeif).

Comment: @mti2935 These aren't ISP ads I'm sure. I have tried on different networks with the same ads showing up.

Comment: @jiheison Yes, the same server is hosting a MySQL database mostly containing test data right now. Are you saying that an attacker would be able to inject a malicious script that could somehow affect my DB?

Comment: The problem would be someone injecting a malicious script into site content stored in the DB, which is then rendered in the browser to trigger pop-ups, data scraping, etc. Some CMS systems store content in a database in a way that attackers can predict and manipulate via several methods. This kind of problem is seen in CMS systems like Wordpress, Magento, etc, but I don't know if it is applicable to Spring-MVC. If your system is storing page content in MySQL, it is worth checking that data for tampering.